# Two different symbols representinɡ a phoneme

Tags: conlang-creation, phonology, phonetics

How would I represent multiple transliterations for one phoneme in a chart?

I was thinking something like this:
`⟨k~q⟩ /k/`

It might work, though it doesn't make the most sense, and I would prefer to use the more common method [if there is one.]

Comment: Your method idea sounds good. You could also add a footnote to the effect of "An alternate glyph for <xyz> is ...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a comma: `⟨k⟩, ⟨q⟩`.

The tilde is a reasonable option, since it means "alternates with depending on context" (i.e. `/k~q/` is a phoneme where `[k]` alternates with `[q]`), but I also associate it very strongly with phonology; when first seeing `⟨k~q⟩ /k/` I mentally transposed the brackets and thought the glyph `⟨k⟩` meant the phoneme `/k~q/`.

Comment: I was looking at some wikipedia pages on orthography a few minutes ago, and I seen it was represented like this: `⟨k/q⟩` So, that's an alternative too.